# java compute hash map using compuateifpresent not working

Tags: java

This is my simple code:

```
public class Main2 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    List<String> names = Arrays.asList("love", "love", "like", "feel", "else");


    names.forEach(s -> {
        map.putIfAbsent(s, 0);
        map.computeIfAbsent(s, v -> map.get(v) + 1);
    });

            map.forEach((k, v) -> {
        System.out.println(String.format("Found key : %s, with value: %s", k, v));
    });
  }
}
```

I wanna count how many times each word exists in that list, but when I print it, the output is always zero

Output:

```
Found key : love, with value: 0
Found key : like, with value: 0
Found key : else, with value: 0
Found key : feel, with value: 0
```

Comment: Do you mean `computeIfPresent()`?

Comment: oh I am stupid, I needed compute if present, but by mistake used the other wrong method

Comment: why use `computeIfPresent` and not just `put`?

Answer (score 4):

Use [`Map::computeIfPresent`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#computeIfPresent(K,java.util.function.BiFunction)) instead :

```
names.forEach(s -> {
    map.putIfAbsent(s, 0);
    map.computeIfPresent(s, (word, count) -> count + 1);
});
```

But as correctly pointed out by davidxxx it is not efficient. It can be substituted by single usage of [`Map::merge`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#merge(K,V,java.util.function.BiFunction)) :

```
names.forEach(s -> {
    map.merge(s, 1, Integer::sum);
});
```

Comment: The first solution is verbose and less efficient because you lookup in the map twice whatever the case while logically it should be done a single time. (+1) for the second solution.

Answer (score 2):

You `put` a value of `0` for each absent key, so `computeIfAbsent` does nothing (since the key is not absent), and all the values remain `0`.

You can write:

```
names.forEach(s -> {
    map.putIfAbsent(s, 0);
    map.put(s,map.get(s) + 1);
});
```

or simpler:

```
names.forEach(s -> {
    map.put(s,map.getOrDefault(s,0) + 1);
});
```

Comment: `merge` is the simples one of those

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you want to count the times when a word is encountered in a collection.

If so, then why not something like this?

```
List<String> words = Arrays.asList("love", "love", "like", "feel", "else");

Map<String, Long> map = words.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        Function.identity(),
        Collectors.counting()
    ));
```

The only difference here is that it uses `Long` to store the counter. If you're not okay with that, in a sense that your `Map` type is fixed, you can replace

```
Collectors.counting()
```

with

```
Collectors.summingInt(e -> 1)
```

And this will yield you the `Map<String, Integer>`.

Answer (score 1):

Here the `Map.merge()` is the most simple and efficient way.

Note that stream is also fine here (it avoids creating explicitly the map) :

```
Map<String, Integer> map =
    names.stream()
         .collect(toMap(s -> s, o -> 1, (v1, v2) -> v1 + v2));
```

Or straighter with a method reference to sum :

```
Map<String, Integer> map =
    names.stream()
         .collect(toMap(s -> s, o -> 1, Integer::sum));
```